# Excel VBA to delete duplicate values in each row

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel report generator which contains some VBA, and with recent requirement changes I'd like to add a function to seek out duplicates in a row and delete them.

[image: Here's how the portion I'd like to enhance looks like]

Basically, I would like to find duplicates in "Client ID1" , "Client ID2" , and "Client ID3" in each row and delete them. I've marked the duplicates in red texts (done manually) to show the example. The report contains approximately 200 rows now and will expand to closer to > 1000 rows as the year progresses.

Thank you in advance for any help and guidance.

Comment: Is the number of Client IDs limited to 3, or could there be more?

Comment: Welcome to SO! There are a minimum requirements at SO. What did you try? Problems seems to be clear but the dataset shall be complete and you should provide the expected output: delete the complete row, delete the data duplicated...???

Comment: Apologies for coming back late - work's been crazy and I had 3 tests in the week to prepare. 

Hello @igittr. The Client IDs are limited to only 3.

Comment: Thank you @DavidGarcíaBodego. At this point, I've tried to re-arrange the Client ID columns in sequence (i.e. columns G, H, I), move it into a new sheet as paste-transpose, apply de-dup, and move it back to the original sheet. It works, but as the database expands I was looking for a more efficient method to do this. The expected output is: to only delete the duplicated data in each row (i.e. the red texts i've highlighted in each row).

Answer (score 0):

Try this, just change what needs to be changed in the top few variables.

```
Public Sub DeleteDuplicateValues()
    Dim strOrderNoCol As String, lngHeaderRow As Long, lngRow As Long
    Dim strSheet As String, objSheet As Worksheet, objDict As Object
    Dim strOrderNo As String, strHeader As String, strClientId As String
    
    strOrderNoCol = "F"
    lngHeaderRow = 1
    strSheet = "Sheet1"
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    
    Set objSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(strSheet)
    
    With objSheet
        For lngRow = lngHeaderRow + 1 To .Rows.Count
            strOrderNo = .Range(strOrderNoCol & lngRow).Text
            If strOrderNo = "" Then Exit For
                
            Set objDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
            
            For lngCol = .Range(strOrderNoCol & "1").Column To .Columns.Count
                strHeader = .Cells(lngHeaderRow, lngCol).Text
                If strHeader = "" Then Exit For
                
                If InStr(1, strHeader, "CLIENT ID", vbTextCompare) = 1 Then
                    strClientId = .Cells(lngRow, lngCol).Text
                    
                    If objDict.Exists(strClientId) Then
                        .Cells(lngRow, lngCol) = ""
                        
                        ' This line will clear out the order value.  If this is not desired, delete this row.
                        .Cells(lngRow, lngCol + 1) = ""
                    Else
                        objDict.Add strClientId, ""
                    End If
                End If
            Next
        Next
    End With

    Set objDict = Nothing
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Skin . I will give this a shot and come back with the result.